# SQL Server to Oracle Language Translator

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have a trigger created in Microsoft SQL Server that I am trying to bring over into Oracle SQL Developer. I realize the syntax and language is a little different. I am slowly but surely trying to work my way through each line, but any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

The trigger in Microsoft SQL Server that I am trying to carry over to Oracle:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Production.Product_Price_Check
ON AdventureWorks.Production.Product FOR UPDATE
AS 
    DECLARE @min_price money; --to keep minimum price
    DECLARE @new_price money; --to keep new price from update query

    SELECT @min_price = (SELECT StandardCost*1.2 FROM INSERTED);
    SELECT @new_price = (SELECT ListPrice FROM INSERTED)
    IF @new_price < @min_price
       BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            -- Rolls back an explicit or implicit transaction to the beginning of the transaction
            PRINT('the price can’t be below ' + cast(@min_price as varchar(20)));
            -- cast is used to convert one data type to another one 
            RAISERROR ('statement was aborted', 6, 1) ;
            return; 
    ELSE PRINT ('Price was successfully changed');     
    END   

GO
```

I'll post updates to where I am at with the new trigger as I am researching:

```
UPDATE Product set ListPrice=42.00 WHERE ProductID=514;
```

Updated Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER Product_Price_Check
   BEFORE UPDATE ON Product
   FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN
         IF :new.listprice < :new.standardcost * 1.2 then
         raise_application_error(-20999, 'The price can not be below' || to_char(:new.standardcost * 1.2));
         RETURN;
         ELSE
           dbms_output.put_line('Price was sucessfully changed');
         END IF;
END;
```

Example code to quickly create Table I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE Product(
    productID int Primary Key,
    name VARCHAR(250),
    ListPrice int Primary Key,
    StandardCost NUMBER(10,4),
);

INSERT INTO Product VALUES(514, 'NLL Mountain Seat Assembly', 133.3400, 98.7700);
```

Comment: we can't write the code for you, if you show your attempt and the specific errors you are facing, you'll get some help

Comment: You can't `rollback` in a trigger

Comment: Why do you want to copy a broken trigger? `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. This trigger sets variables using two separate `SELECT`s from this table that will take one row's value and ignore the rest (with no guarantee that they're even from the same row). Bad starting point.

Comment: Also, it looks like this should just be a `CHECK` constraint anyway.

Comment: I'm SUPER new to this

Comment: The second `raise_application_error()` will never executed as processing of the trigger stops with the first.

Answer (score 6):

In either Oracle or SQL Server, it looks like the trigger is unnecessary and what you should instead write:

```
ALTER TABLE Production.Product ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Product_Prices
CHECK (ListPrice >=StandardCost * 1.2);
```

This avoids writing any *procedural* logic at all and instead is using *declarative* rules. These are usually preferred because at times, the optimizer can make use of them to eliminate portions of a query which couldn't possibly produce any results.

Answer (score 5):

The most fundamental difference between triggers in Oracle and SQL Server are, that Oracle uses **row level** triggers by default - something that is not available with SQL Server. As far as I can tell, all you want to do is to check if the new values of updated row comply with certain rules.

```
CREATE or replace TRIGGER Product_Price_Check_trg
  BEFORE UPDATE ON Product 
  FOR EACH ROW -- this makes it a row level trigger
AS 
begin
  if :new.listprice < :new.standardcost * 1.2 then 
    raise_application_error(-20999, 'The price can''t be below ' || to_char(:new.listprice));
  end if;
end;
/
```

Because of the exception the transaction doing this has to be rolled back.

More details on the syntax and examples how to create a trigger can be found [in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html#GUID-AF9E33F1-64D1-4382-A6A4-EC33C36F237B)

---

However there is no need for a trigger, a check constraint will be **much** more efficient (in Oracle just as well as in SQL Server)

```
create table product
(
   standardcost number,
   listprice    number, 
   constraint check_price check (listprice < standardcost * 1.2)
);
```

Comment: Did you have to declare 'new.standardcost'?

Comment: got it, forgot the : before the new.standardcost

Comment: @Sam: corrected, thanks. But you should really use a check constraint for that. The whole trigger approach was a really bad idea to begin with (not to mention the broken logic in the SQL Server trigger)

Comment: I agree, I've just been told to do this lol. Thanks for the help and information.

Comment: The trigger seems to be running backwards. I updated my post with my code and sample table info

Comment: @Sam: then switch the condition.